# How do I subset a data frame by multiple different categories

Tags: r, error-handling, subset

I'm trying to subset a data frame by a number of categories.

For example - my dataset looks similar to this

[image]

What I want to do is subset this data frame so I have only the samples from Categories B1, O1 and H1, and response variables 1 and 3, without having to count rows or columns (the actual dataset is quite large)

I tried to do this with the following code:

```
mydata <- subset(df, 
                 Category == ("B1", "O1", "H1"), 
                 select = c(Response variable 1, Response variable 3))
```

However I keep getting the following error:

> Error in drop && length(x) == 1L : invalid 'x' type in 'x && y'

Just wondering what the best way to subset a dataset like this is?

Comment: Try `Category %in% ("B1", "O1", "H1")` instead and see if that works

Comment: `subset(df,Category %in% c("B1", "O1", "H1"), select = c('Response variable 1', 'Response variable 3'))`

Answer (score 0):

This is the sort of operation where the tidyverse (and {dplyr} in particular) really shines.  You can combine the `filter()` and `select()` functions to do this e.g.

```r
## create an example data.frame
df <- data.frame(Category = c("B1", "O1", "H1", "C1", "K1"),
                 RV1 = c(1,2,4,5,7),
                 RV2 = c(7,8,4,5,6),
                 RV3 = c(1,4,5,2,4))

## load the dplyr package
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  filter(Category %in% c("B1", "O1", "H1")) %>%
  select(RV1, RV3)
#>   RV1 RV3
#> 1   1   1
#> 2   2   4
#> 3   4   5
```

Answer (score 0):

For `Category`, you need to use `%in%` instead of `==` (as others mentioned in the comments). You are getting the error because `==` expects items to be of equal length on each side. For example, if you were to do `rep(df$Category, 3) == c("B1", "O1", "H1")`, then you would not get the error. What you want here is to be able to determine if a given element is in a vector, so using `%in%` will check if an item is in the list or not (a logical). So, `subset` will return the rows that our `TRUE` from that condition. Then, in the `select` statement, you need to use quotation marks around the full names.

```
mydata <- subset(df, Category %in% c("B1", "O1", "H1"),
                 select = c("Response variable 1", "Response variable 3"))
```

**Output**

```
mydata

  Response variable 1 Response variable 3
1                   1                   1
2                   2                   4
3                   4                   5
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Category = c("B1", "O1", "H1", "C1", "K1"), `Response variable 1` = c(1, 
2, 4, 5, 7), `Response variable 2` = c(7, 8, 4, 5, 6), `Response variable 3` = c(1, 
4, 5, 2, 4)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```